# Laravel 5.2 : Session values doesn't persist across different routes?

Tags: php, laravel, session

*I'm using `Laravel 5.2`. (And i'm a new Laravel user)*

I need to use **Session**. And of course, read the Session Values from different Routes/pages. Here is the simple concept, simply:

1. Save some session values from a route.
2. Retrieve the values from another different route.

Here's the code i used.

```
Route::get('write', function () {
    session()->put('food', 'banana');
    session()->save();
    echo session()->get('food'); // <------ Shows: 'banana'
});

Route::get('read', function () {
    echo session()->get('food'); // <------ Shows nothing*
});
```

- What did i miss (or) what is the proper way to play with Sessions please?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `session()->pull()` actually pulls an element from the session and deletes it from session. So after `/write` called you'll have nothing in you session. That's why `/read` can not pull anything.

You should use `session()->get('food')` in your scenario instead of `pull`.
Also make sure that your routes use `web` middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('write', function () {
        session()->put('food', 'banana');
        echo session()->get('food'); // <------ Shows: 'banana'
    });

    Route::get('read', function () {
        echo session()->get('food'); // <------ Shows 'banana' too
    });
});
```

Also check the official documentation for further read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session.

Comment: Changed to `session()->get('food')` already (in both routes). Still doesn't help.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. It seems, that you do not use proper middleware for your routes.

Comment: OMG. It must be like that? That is such a big mess. :S

Comment: Does it work for you? It does for me:)
In Laravel 5.2 basic web features, like sessions, are implemented through `web` middleware. That's why you need to enable it for you routes. Nothing difficult, but a little piece of work though.

Comment: Yup it works that way. Thanks so much! But is it the "only" way now in 5.2 please? Seems quite messy already. :S

Comment: And it does also requires this call `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of the file. (Please mention about this in your answer. So that i can mark it as the Answer.)

Comment: I'm afraid, it does not for this example. All that code from the answer is the only code I put into `routes.php`. Nothing else required there (http://prntscr.com/amqz2h). Of course, if you need to use `Request` data in your route callbacks, you should import that namespace, but for current situation it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

use `session()->save()` after you put or modify something in it.

I usually do it via the facade `Session::save()`;

If it isn't saved the session object wont know about it.

Comment: Sure for LV 5.2 please?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7f62d81acb2001faafb21a32544464ebfc92476c/tests/Session/SessionStoreTest.php#L118

Comment: Oh thanks. But that works with `5.1` only. Not for `5.2`. :)